# The sum of $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

Tags: calculus

I would like to prove that $\sum_i \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$ is finite but I have no idea.

Could you help me please? I searched on google but there is not information.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I assume that $i=n$?  Hint:  it's a Geometric Series.

Comment: Oh right, I have thought about it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

For an infinite Gemetric series Id est
 $$S=1+x+x^2+x^3+ \ldots$$ (where $|x|<1$)

S is given by

> $$S=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

For your question, $x=\dfrac{1}{4}$

Also see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series?wprov=sfla1) Wikipedia article on Geometric Series (You can find the above written formula in the head **Sum** $\rightarrow$ **Formula**).